# How to solve the scheduling problem with random durations? (undomoves will result different scores)

Tags: optaplanner

"A shadow variable is in essence the result of a formula/algo based on at least 1 planning variable (and maybe some problem properties). The same planning variables state should always deliver the exact same shadow variable state." However, for project scheduling problems with random durations, even the start time of a job remains the same as before move or undomove, the end time of the job will be different, because the duration is a random variable. Both the start time and the end time of a job are shadow variables. Then the score after undomove and beforemove will be different. How to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

> Then the score after undomove and beforemove will be different.

That is the root of your problem. Assume a solution X and a move M. Move M transforms solution X into solution Y. Undo move M2 must then transform solution Y back into solution X. (X and Y do not need to, and are not going to, be the same instance; they just need to represent the exact same state of the problem.)

Where you fall short is in modelling random duration of tasks. Every time the duration of a task changes, that is a change to the problem. When task duration changes, you are no longer solving the same problem - and you need to tell the solver that.

There are two ways of doing that:

- [Externally via `ProblemChange`](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/repeated-planning/repeated-planning.html#problemChange). This will effectively restart the solver.
- [During a custom move](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/move-and-neighborhood-selection/move-and-neighborhood-selection.html#customMoves), using `ScoreDirector`'s `before...()` and `after...()` methods. But if you do that, then your undo moves *must* restore the solution back to its original state. They must reset the duration to what it was before.

There really is no way around this. Undo moves restore the solution to the exact same state as there was before the original move.

That said, I honestly do not understand how you implement randomness in your planning entities. If you share your code, maybe I will be able to give a more targetted answer.

Comment: "That said, I honestly do not understand how you implement randomness in your planning entities." In the OptaPlanner's project job scheduling problem, the duration of a job is predefined and is a certain value. Then the end time of the job equals the start time+duration. However, in our problem, the duration depends on the state of the machine. For example, at a time point T1, a solution X was transformed to a solution Y with a move M. Then, at a time point T2, undomove M2 transforms sulution Y back into X (planning variables are the same for X and Y).  Continued in the following comment...

Comment: Although the undomove transforms Y back into X, the time point T2 can not be changed backed to T1. Then, the duration of the job will be different at time point T2, compared to that at T1. Then, this will result that two solutions have the same planning variables, but with different job stat times and end times. So the score will be different.

Comment: And I do not understand clearly the mechanism of undomoves. Is there must an undomove after each move? or the undomove is carried out after several moves?

Comment: The are two stages - first, the solver tries a whole bunch of moves to see which is best. All of these moves are immediately undone, that is why they need to return to the original solution. The best move is then applied, and not undone - this is the move that actually changes the solution. After these two stages, it starts all over again, also called "a step".